# Gateway Response Customization in case of request validation failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, openapi, aws-api-gateway

**Background**

I am trying to validate the request (body and parameters) in the openapi specification file, which I in turn, use to create my integrations (to AWS LAMBDA functions) from the AWS API Gateway. I am using the aws extensions - `x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator` to perform the schema validation of the request body.

**Requirement**

When there is a schema validation failure, I intend to catch the same and customize the error message using the approach documented in [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-responses-in-swagger.html).

As it can be observed from the article, the custom response is constructed as an `application/json` type and the error response template has been defined. However, I have defined an "ErrorResponseMessage" model in my openapi specification file and I would like to use the same in the scenario I have explained above.

I am not sure how this can be achieved. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Below are the relevant sections from my openapi file:

```
x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  request-body-only: 
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: false
  params-only:
    validateRequestBody: false
    validateRequestParameters: true  
  full:
    validateRequestBody: true
    validateRequestParameters: true

paths:
  /test:
    post:
      x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: request-body-only
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              $ref: '#/components/schemas/CreateRequest'
      responses:
        "400":
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessageResponse'
components:
    ErrorMessageResponse:
      type: object
      properties:
        statusCode:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          example: 400
        message:
          type: string
          example: Unexpected error.
        errors:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessage'
    ErrorMessage:
      type: object
      properties:
        code:
          type: string
          example: UnexpectedError
        message:
          type: string
          example: Unexpected error.
        type:
          type: string
        id:
          type: string
```

I would like to catch the validation errors and transform the error response on the API Gateway itself like below using the aws open-api extensions (to be added in the openapi specification file)

```
x-amazon-apigateway-gateway-responses: 
  BAD_REQUEST_BODY: 
    statusCode: '400'
    responseTemplates: 
      application/json:
        schema:
          $ref: '#/components/schemas/ErrorMessageResponse'
```

As one can notice, the intention here is to transform the error response to "ErrorMessageResponse" but I am not sure how I can achieve it.